# How to Obtain “Right” Parameters of Multinomial Logit Model (or Other Conditional Models) in R?

Tags: r, multinomial-distribution, logit, nnet

I started to use the function `multinom` of `R` package `nnet` in order to fit several conditional probability distributions with the multinomial logistic model. I need the parameters of the fittings in order to pass them to a Java program, which will compute the probabilities and use them.

My problem is that the probabilities computed with the parameters returned by `multinom`, following the usual [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression#As_a_set_of_independent_binary_regressions) of multinomial logistic model, are not the same as those directly computed in `R`, which are the correct ones. On Stack Overflow I have already asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905807/how-does-the-function-multinom-from-r-package-nnet-compute-the-multinomial-proba) about this issue, but I do not still know how the `R` function `multinom` computes these probabilities; my guess is that it relies on neural networks, since this function belongs to `R` package `nnet`, but I do not have any idea about the details, and an inspection of the code led to nowhere.

Do you know an `R` package which fits conditional probabilities and returns the corresponding parameters of the model, so that we may easily compute the probabilities in another program? E.g., using the MARS model (`R` package `earth`) or Projection Pursuit Regression (`R` package `ppr`) is not feasible, since computing the probabilities from the parameters of these models would be a mess. Besides, the function `mlogit` from the `R` package with the same name is not applicable as well, since the dataset should be in a certain format (we would also need the predictors corresponding to the alternative, "non-chosen" response variable).